# Packets dropped by kernel during load testing of haproxy -> node.js -> db

Tags: node.js, haproxy

we are in the process of load testing our game server stack, which consists of haproxy/ssl -> node.js (app servers) -> database

The calls are gets which then node.js passes to the db then returns data back to the client, how ever during various testing we are seeing various odd issues that we cant seem to track down.

While running tcpdump 'tcp[13] & 4!=0' | grep http-alt

We see various things in the log:

`23:35:16.049886 IP xx > xx.http-alt: Flags [R], seq 2946709660, win 0, length 0
23:35:16.668370 IP xx.62737 > xx.http-alt: Flags [R.], seq 4204676699, ack 3037703652, win 68, options [nop,nop,TS val 153103530 ecr 133109021], length 0
23:36:06.030500 IP xx.40290 > xx.http-alt: Flags [R.], seq 431162404, ack 2610577956, win 68, options [nop,nop,TS val 153115871 ecr 133121361], length 0`

Exiting the command we see

1662286 packets received by filter
9 packets dropped by kernel

our load testing apps also returns errors back to us.. along the lines of this

`T000023 --- loop started --- 19 Aug 2013 18:09:07.975 ---r"
    T000023r"
    T000023 <<< user_id = nullr"
    T000023 <<< ext_userid = nullr"
    T000023 <<< Public_token_put = nullr"
    T000023 <<< Private_token_prt = nullr"
    T000023 >>> execute plug-in #1: GenerateRandomCharactersr"
    T000023r"
    T000023r"
    T000023 # Page #1: Registrationr"
    T000023 # ---------------------r"
    T000023r"
    T000023 [1] GET https://someurl.com:2222/?method=somemethod&type=reg=somerandomid ...r"
    T000023 -8 (Network Connection aborted by Server), [No Content Type], --- bytes, --- ms, * Failed at 'Open Network Connection', java.net.SocketException: Connection resetr"
    T000023  error: expected HTTP status: 200 <> received: -8 (Network Connection aborted by Server), [No Content Type], --- bytes, --- ms, ** Failed at 'Open Network Connection', java.net.SocketException: Connection resetr`

Any thoughts on where to start..

servers are ubuntu 12.04 server with one tweak to sysctl

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 262144

Answer (score 3):

The tcpdump errors are a red haring (meaning they are not related to your problem). TCPDump tries to stay out of the way of impacting system performance. If the system would get backed up for something that tcpdump is doing then it will simply drop the packet instead of inspecting it. This does not mean that the system or network stack is dropping packets. Try adding the "-n" switch to tcpdump.

```
-n     Don't convert addresses (i.e.,  host  addresses,  port  numbers, etc.) to names.
```

Unless you have a caching DNS server like dnsmasq installed, nscd is more than likely disabled. This means that for every connection that comes in tcpdump will try to do a reverse dns lookup. I bet that by adding the -n your "dropped packets" go away.

Your real problem sounds to me like you are either overwhelming system resources (cpu, memory, etc) or you are exceeding your ephemeral ports/max connections in haproxy. Also it is very well documented that conntrack + haproxy is a recipe for terrible performance.

1. Disable conntrack
2. Check your max connections config in haproxy
3. Look at the haproxy stats page (if it is not configured, configure it - it is awesome!)
4. Enable haproxy logging. I run a very large haproxy implementation using version 1.5.19. We have been using 1.5.x for almost a year now with no issues. One thing that I have learned is that haproxy logging is always 100% reliable. Sometimes I misinterpreted the log entry, but it was always accurate. In scenarios like this where you are trying to track down a connection problem, the haproxy logging will simply tell you why it is failing.
5. Check the max open file handles for the haproxy process. To do this

`cat /proc/(haproxy PID)/limits`

Good luck.

PS. Enable stats page, it is awesome! Also, enable haproxy logging, it is also awesome! Between these two you will be able to identify the connection issue very quickly.

Comment: Regarding conntrack, this appears to be enabled by default on the virtual servers that are being load balanced by haproxy as opposed to haproxy itself. Maxconn is set to 10k which, according to the stats, it is not coming close to with these 500 user concurrency tests. It is worth noting though that it is harder to see because of `nbproc 8`, though it isn't close on each sample even at 8x. Perhaps we are not getting the connection resets logged with `log /dev/log local0` or we are not interpreting them correctly but here are the most common samples (following comment)

Comment: Aug 21 18:34:35 lb10 haproxy[5458]: 1.2.3.4:58656 [21/Aug/2013:18:34:22.456] http-in~ user_group/n30 35/0/1194/-1/+12629 -1 +0 - - SD-- 152/152/106/106/0 0/0 "GET /?query=string HTTP/1.1"
    Aug 21 18:34:40 lb10 haproxy[5458]: 1.2.3.4:40358 [21/Aug/2013:18:34:35.361] http-in~ user_group/n30 93/0/5020/25/+5138 200 +157 - - ---- 378/378/369/369/1 0/0 "GET /?query=string HTTP/1.1"

We have option httplog, logasap, dontlog-normal, dontlognull enabled. Is there anything else specific from the stats page that we should be trying to use to help isolate? Perhaps retries / re-dispatches?

Comment: Actually the log message is perfect. You may want to look up the logging format to understand what each of the fields mean. They even show tcp connection time etc. The "SD" in the log means that haproxy received a received a RST (reset) during the data transfer coming from the backend server. Do an ifconfig on your systems to look for dropped packets. You may also want to do a tcpdump on your haproxy server and filter for traffic coming from your backend server. 
http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#8.5

Comment: Sorry, the above message was too long. At the same time that you are doing a capture on the haproxy server, also do a capture on your backend server. Wait for an error and then open up both captures and look for the failure in one of them. Once you find it in one capture you can look it up by tcp session ID in the other. What you are looking for is a miss-match between the packets. There is probably a RST that shows up on the haproxy server that did not come from the backend server. If this is the case it is time to start looking at filtering software, firewalls, or switches.

Comment: Ah yes, the log format explanation helps a lot. Based on that evaluation, I think we were able to get rid of the 200's being logged that seemed to be reaching the `timeout client` threshold if I understood the output correctly. Also removed logasap to get more accurate information. Hmm... ifconfig doesn't seem to indicate dropped packets. I saw iftop previously and that also didn't seem to indicate resets. The CCI instances are running iptables, otherwise it may be the datacenter. We are seeing packet loss across the board. How does one look up the tcp session ID? Between the tcpdump results?

Comment: What I usually do is just line up the source/destination ports for a given time frame. The source on one host will be the destination on the other and visa verse.

Comment: These are the two most common tcpdump results that can be seen on both servers -- `21:14:45.256516 IP 10.62.9.196.42449 > 10.84.173.72.8080: Flags [R.], seq 1866446488, ack 470802873, win 135, options [nop,nop,TS val 24030887 ecr 48679029], length 0` -- `19:14:46.960640 IP 10.84.173.72.8080 > 10.62.9.196.47077: Flags [R], seq 3850037434, win 0, length 0`

Comment: Here is more samples which seem to show that while they do match up for the most part, they do not always: http://pastie.org/private/ikgecg5y7yjg7zvfxg8uww

Comment: Hmm, if your capture is correct it appears that something on the network is sending a reset to both sides of the connection (haproxy and backend server). I have personally run into this 3 times. BGP - VERY unlikely, firewall/router/switch, content filtering software.

Comment: mmhmm. Well, while BGP does seem unlikely (good read!), we are using a provider where we are relying on private network communication that sounds like it would indeed use BGP. We have them looking into the considerable amount of packet loss we're experiencing between all servers at high concurrency, and while we're remaining optimistic, it is a big scary that our backbone may be fragile in this way. I know this isn't exactly making a sandwich we're doing here, but I will say that we really, really really, appreciate you taking a look at this.

Comment: Is there anything else we can do or provide that may help? They have had us run some tests with iperf that they're saying suggest we need to increase our TCP window size which we have just done with some sysctl.conf changes that we had previously applied and seemed to have issues with. Trying small changes at a time instead of a bunch though. Primarily just these right now, per their recommendation: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/

Comment: At this point it sounds like it is defiantly related to the network between your haproxy server and the backend server. If you have a provider that is responsible for managing the network then it sounds like you are in the right hands in working with them. Good luck!

Comment: dtorgo, thanks for your help kevin and I have been battling this for a bit, also trying to figure out if our node.js app is rejecting data because its coming in to fast.. we are doing high concurrent users per sec test for an upcoming game we working on.

Comment: @dtorgo - Could you explain to me what the implications of disabling conntrack are?  You would loose Iptables support then I suppose? Thanks